# How to copy table and data from one database to another database using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have two database servers

one is server name: X and other one is server name: Y

I have a table `ABC` in both databases. I need to copy the data from X server, table `ABC` to the Y server, table `ABC`.

I tried this way its giving error.

```
INSERT INTO [X].Database.dbo.ABC SELECT * FROM [Y].Database.dbo.ABC
```

but I get this error:

> Could not find server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the
>   stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: Have you run `sp_addlinkedserver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up SSMS and point it to Server Y.  Right click on database ABC, Tasks -> Import Data.  Follow the wizard and point it at your source data in Server X.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you what to do. Use sp_addlinkedserver  to create a linked server to the remote server. Then run the query.

Answer (score 0):

First exec procedure:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
@server=N'Y', 
@srvproduct=N'',
@provider=N'SQLNCLI', 
@datasrc=N'Y\instance1';
```

Then run the query.